In filamentphp fileupload image is not visible while edit/update
Below code is used for fileupload. But while editing image is not appearing. We need to again upload same image
‘’’
Forms\Components\FileUpload::make(‘photo’)->disk(‘s3’)->directory(‘image’)->visibility(‘public’)->acceptedFileTypes([‘image/jpeg’, ‘image/png’,’image/webp’])
‘’’

The issue could indeed be related to CORS or an URL mismatch between the APP_URL in the .env file and the URL used in the browser. If your APP_URL is set as APP_URL=http://localhost:8000, you should access the application using http://localhost:8000, not http://127.0.0.1:8000.
